# Elasticsearch Not Using Pipeline In Bulk Updates

Tags: elasticsearch, pipeline

I'm unable to get elasticsearch to use my defined pipeline when making bulk updates. It works fine with bulk indexes, but not bulk updates.

My pipeline-

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/subscriber_pipeline
{
  "description" : "Sets the document last_updated time",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "script" : {
        "lang" : "painless",
        "inline" : """
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date = new Date();
        ctx.last_updated = df.format(date);
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My bulk update request-

```
POST subscribers/_bulk?pipeline=subscriber_pipeline
{"update":{"_index":"subscribers","_type":"subscriber","_id":"abcdefg","retry_on_conflict":20,"pipeline":"subscriber_pipeline"}}
{"doc":{"domain_id":100,"subscribed_date":"2019-12-18T23:27:12","subscribed_url":"https://acme.com/"},"doc_as_upsert":true}
```

Are pipelines not supported for update and bulk update operations?

Answer (score 0):

pipeline should put in json
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

like

```
POST _bulk
```

{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1" ,"pipeline":"pipeline-name"} }
{ "field1" : "value1" }

Comment: You're right. The actual problem was that pipeline aren't supported for updates at all, only index.

Comment: That's true @micah and how do you work around it finally?

Comment: @puppylpg I solved it in application. All of my updates funneled through a custom ingest pipeline where I could add logic to bump the LUA timestamp for all update records

Comment: @micah Thanks, and what about batch update? Seems that you didn't leverage bulk to update?

Comment: @puppylpg We did. All updates went to a queue, a process collected them in batches, modified the documents (bumped LUA timestamp), then sent a bulk update request to Elasticsearch.

Comment: @micah Gotcha, thanks for your kindness. Does that mean you didn't use ingest pipeline in elaticsearch to set the field? Our ingest pipeline is complicated, thus must be implemented in Elasticsearch. Seems that the only way to leverage ingest pipeline is to give up batch update, and send the request one by one.

Comment: That's correct. We did not use Elasticsearch Ingest Pipeline in the end